# Is it possible to retrieve more than 50 comments of a Post object?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Downloading `https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed?limit=500&access_token=TOKEN`, gives me the all entries in that group (I collect more posts using `paging->next`).

But, after reviewing some posts, I see that there are at least 500 comments, but the feed returns only 50.

I don't see any pagination for dealing with the comments, so how can I "ask" for more?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to manually request all the fields, but you can request more comments using [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/).

```
.../GROUP_ID/feed?fields=comments.limit(100)&limit=...
```

Comment: Executing it returns `An unknown error occurred`. Am I doing something wrong? (of course there is a valid GROUP_ID, all I add was the `fields` parameter).

Comment: It works for me on my groups in the Graph API explorer. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: I figured the problem: when I lowered the `limit` parameter to 100, and the limit of the comments to 20, I get data. Testing with higher values works in the Graph API explorer, so it's seems to be a problem on my side. Could it be that too much information is returned, and an overflow occurs?

Comment: It could be. You can test this by pasting your URL complete with a valid access token in the address bar of a browser. If you get data, complete with paging links then you know it's on your receiving end.

Comment: I have overcome the problem. Removing the `limit` parameter, and downloading my data page by page solved it. Thank you so much! ;)